# Why can't I call bt_get_backtrace() in QNX?

Tags: qnx, backtrace, qnx-neutrino, blackberry-qnx

I wanted to backtrace the funtions in stack in my QNX program, so I consulted the API in the official documentation of QNX. I followed the example code in the official document to call bt_get_backtrace() in libbacktrace.so, but it returns -1 and the program reported an error stating "Not Spportted".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK8Pz.jpg)

However, I can load and print memmap successfully by calling bt_load_memmap and bt_sprn_memmap.

How can I solve this problem? Is there any other way to do backtrace? I have try exeinfo.h and libunwind but both of them doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libbacktrace on QNX does not support backtraces on aarch64. You're better off using libunwind [0].

[0] https://github.com/libunwind/libunwind